# Spam and random users registering in Laravel

Tags: laravel, email, hosting

On my current project im getting random users registering (no account verified) and sending me mails (contact form). Example:

*Name: vYTWgQbatMAhlLCs Lastname: nbAsZztVco Mail: brian.t.gordon@gmail.com*

*Name: WLjdJxYstI Lastname: ZaXsdnrKDejy Mail: sales@signreflections.com*

And i receive more than 10 of this on a day.

Despite the fact this is not an extremely critical problem, something is wrong. Im receiving a lot of mails with these fake users and its not normal. Im using reCaptcha but it seems cant solve this problem.

Solutions? Code problem? An attack? Hosting problems? Thanks.

Comment: When you're already using a captcha solution then this is most likely a human submitting those.
You could ban their IP or specific IP ranges but this isn't really a problem to bypass and could impact other visitors using a VPN. Since it seems like they are using random characters you could assume that the time from opening the site to submitting the form isn't that long so you could block all submits that didn't take longer than x seconds (but don't show that).

Comment: I've faced the same problem, I have captcha too on my email page. In my db I have `mails` table, where I stored all email info. I blocked all spam email by IP, a user can send me one email per 10 minutes